# System.IO.DriveInfo() for a remote drive or volume

Tags: c#, .net

Can I reference another server so that I can get drive information from it using System.IO.DriveInfo().

Comment: manuell - those posts do not answer the question I asked. I asked if I could use System.IO Namespace from a remote computer. I already know how to use System.Management Namespace. Please read the question carefully before answering. If my question is not clear, please ask before voting down. Thanks.

Comment: The answer, implicitly, is no. People, probably believing that the problem to be solved was to access drives on remote machines are pointing you towards resources for doing so. But if the problem has some weird constraint, such that it has to use classes in the `System.IO` namespace, then it has no solution.